# How to ingest data from ADLS into Azure Data Explorer by subscribing to Event Grid

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to ingest data from ADLS gen2 to Azure data explorer through Event Grid.
I could find a few of MSFT docs explaining about how to ingest blobs into ADX through event grid but not ADLS.

[image]

the file path to the ADLS storage account is abfss://container@p01lakesstor.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/projectname/A/data/json/

I just would like to know how to set the prefix/suffix here to read the data from that adls storage account

would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the work

> /blobServices/default/containers/mycontainer/blobs/this/is/my/path/

Replace `mycontainer` and `/this/is/my/path/` with the relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

Please be mindful of ADLS subtleties when setting up Event Grid subscriptions:

[Writing ADLSv2 files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview#upload-blobs)

[Known ADLSv2 limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview#known-event-grid-issues)